# Error: Crystal Reports - "errorKind"

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

Tengo un reporte hecho en Crystal Reports. El reporte funciona bien, pero aparece este error al momento de generar el reporte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según el mensaje de error, se muestra un error en la formula que a continuación les doy:

```
if {registros1.subcartera}= 'CARTA 1'
then "PRIMER AVISO DE COBRANZA"
else 
if {registros1.subcartera}= 'CARTA 2'
then "SEGUNDO AVISO DE COBRANZA"
else 
    if {registros1.subcartera}= 'CARTA 3'
    then "TERCER AVISO DE COBRANZA"
    else 
        if {registros1.subcartera}='CARTA NOTARIAL' or {registros1.subcartera}='NOTARIAL'
        then 'CARTA NOTARIAL'
```

La información la extraigo de una base de datos MySQL, pero en esto no tengo problemas ya que la información sí llega.

**[Edito]**
Adjunto URL al código fuente en Github: 
https://github.com/rickymuvel/errorCrystal

**[Edito]**
Reporte:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu reporte no tiene un campo que se llame `{registros1.subcartera}`. En vez de imagen habría sido más útil mostrar el código a través del cual se  genera tu reporte.

Comment: Es decir, sugieres que el error está en Visual Basic? de qué forma podría mostrarte el código?

Comment: No uso Crystal Reports, pero imagino que construye el reporte en formato XML... en alguna parte del programa debes tener la opción de mostrarte la fuente (source)  de tu reporte, que suele ser un XML. ¿Has revisado todos los campos del reporte? Debe haber uno que se llame `{registros1.subcartera}`. Eso es lo que dice el mensaje de error, que busca ese campo pero no lo encuentra.

Comment: No encuentro el archivo XML que mencionas, la verdad me he visto obligado a usar Visual Basic por requerimiento del trabajo, tampoco lo domino, por eso recurro a su ayuda. He editado mi post y he añadido un link a Github, podrías echarme un cable? saludos

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el reporte, el archivo?

Comment: Se llama rptCartasRpp.rpt, ese es el que uso:
https://github.com/rickymuvel/errorCrystal/tree/master/reportes/rpp/carta1

Comment: No veo nada... en tu reporte debes tener un campo que se llame **tipoCarta** y dentro de ese campo una fórmula que hace referencia al campo `{registros1.subcartera}`. Ese campo no existe en tu reporte.

Comment: Sí, en el reporte tengo el campo tipoCarta, el cual, cuando edito tengo la formula que he añadido en el menú principal. Por cierto, he añadido un screenshot de mi reporte y la variable **tipoCarta**. No tengo idea que pueda estar ocurriendo.

Comment: No entiendo a lo que te refieres: _cuando edito tengo la formula que he añadido en el menú principal._ El mensaje de error dice que en el campo tipoCarta está buscando esto `{registros1.subcartera}` y no lo encuentra, porque es lo que preguntas en tu código `if {registros1.subcartera}= 'CARTA 1' then "PRIMER AVISO DE COBRANZA" ... `. En Jasper Report por ejemplo los nombres de campo tienen algo como `$F{registros1.subcartera}` pero de Crystal Report no se... La lógica es que recibes un dato en `{registros1.subcartera}` que sería otro campo del reporte y lo comparas en tipoCarta.

Comment: Si abres la pestaña parameter fields, a la izquierda de tu programa, es posible que estén ahí los campos con parámetros, o en special fields.

Comment: Solo hay un campo que representa la fecha de impresión,y es una variable de texto plano, no almacena info de la base de datos..

Comment: Entonces el if... que sentido tiene ? Si quitas eso temporalmente del campo tipoCarta que pasa ?

Comment: Perdona la demora. Si lo quito sigue apareciendo el mismo problema... la verdad no se que más hacer... creo que voy a probar con otro reporteador...

Comment: ¿No pudiste resolverlo? Otra posibilidad sería verificar el DataSource de tu reporte, o sea, la base de datos a la que está ligado. ¿Sabrías hacer eso en Cristal Report?